# the Intersection of smooth curves can be countable but not finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, curves

Given two parametric $C^{1}$ curves in $R^{k}$, i.e. $\xi$ $\eta$ whose parametrization are defined on subsets $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ such that the ending points $\xi(b)=\eta(d)$. Assume that $\dot{\xi}\ne=0$. Can 
$\xi$ $\eta$ intersect on a countable set but not finite set?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you really not find an example?! Draw one

Comment: I mean: you have surely seen the graph of the function $x^2\sin 1/x$ or something similar.

Comment: You can actually make the intersection an uncountable set having no intervals in it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example $(x,0)$ and $(x, x^4 \sin(\pi/x))$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$:
[image]

The intersections are clearly countable, by making the correspondence between integers $i$ and $1/i$.

Note that the derivative at 0 is:

${d \over d x} x^4 \sin(\pi/x) = 4 x^3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)-\pi  x^2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)$ which is $0$ for the limit $x \to 0$.

Comment: While I agree one the idea I disagree on some technical details. The curve $(x, \sin \frac1x)$ is not differentiable at \(0,0\). Moreover, the endpoints condition $\xi(c)=\eta(d)$ is not satisfied.

Comment: is the derivative continuous at $0$?

Comment: @FrancescoCiardiello:  Is that necessary for the problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes, it is. I am looking for two parametrized curves smooth at $b$ and $d$ respectively.

Comment: Maybe $x^{4} sin(1/x)$ should work.

Comment: However I am looking for not a curve whose derivative is defined at $b$ or $d$ a not a curve whose derivative can be extended by continuity at $0$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork your new example is not even continuous at $0$. I think multiplying the sinusoid by $x^2$ and using the zero function instead of that quadratic should fix it.

Comment: Multiply by $e^{-1/x}$ instead of $x^4$ and you'll have a $C^\infty$ example.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: With $x^2$ you will have differentiable but not $C^1$, but $x^3$ will do $C^1$, and as zhw pointed out one can easily get a $C^\infty$ version.